# Community wikis - are they ever a possibility?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, questions, policy, too-broad

After seeing [this question on shared worlds](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/1396/253) and [this one](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1348/what-software-can-prototype-a-solar-system), I'm wondering whether such questions are better handled as community wikis, or even if they would be on-topic if broad enough to work as community wikis.

The question is, is there any class of question that is not too broad on this Q&A that could become a community wiki? Is that ever an alternative to broad questions that can work as lists of answers?

Comment: So far I've not seen one. That doesn't mean they don't exist though.

Comment: We have a couple on meta that are doing their job :-) Help Center and Community Ad Promotion